# How to get my app-engine home page from a Servlet

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets

I have created an app-engine connected android project. The way this works is when you open your `webapp` directory there is an `index.html`, which serves as the home page of the api. What I want is to create a Servlet that will generate that home page for me instead of serving it from this `webapp/index.html`. I have created my servlet. But I am not sure how to refer to it inside `web.xml`

I imagine I have to replace

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep it simple you can remove the static *index.html* altogether and create a servlet mapping like this (in web.xml).

```
<servlet>
     <servlet-name>MyWelcomeServlet<servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>domain.package.subpackage.class</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>MyWelcomeServlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/index.html</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

Note: removing or renaming the static *index.html* is important since Google's content delivery network will serve static files before routing requests to app engine instances.

Comment: thanks for the response. I am not able to test presently. So +1. Will let you know how it goes when I am able to test again.